# Continuously logging exceptions to a file using threads in android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a requirement where in I have to create a text file in the sd card and then every time through out the application if I get any exception I have to log it into the text file. Everything should happen in a thread.

At some places, I have a thread running and that gives some exception and in this case how do I start a new thread from this thread to log.

My Questions: 
How do I log each and every exception from a new thread.
Can we start a new thread from some other thread.
How do I destroy the thread if I want to use a same thread for writing each and every log to a file although I know it's not recommended to run a thread more than once. 
Is it possible to do this without using log4j.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you have a dedicated thread with a work queue for your entire application like so:

```
class Logging {
    public static ExecutorService logger = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
}
```

Then when an exception is caught:

```
try {
   ...
} catch(Exception ex) {
   Logging.logger.submit(new LoggingJob(ex));
}
```

where `LoggingJob` can be something like:

```
class LoggingJob implements Runnable {
    private Exception ex;

    public LoggingJob(Exception ex) {
        this.ex = ex;
    }

    public void run() {
        // write ex to log file
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Tudor for the answer. I will definitely try this and come back with the reply asap.

Comment: +1 Nice.  A `submit()` method on `Logging` would be cleaner of course.  ;-)

Comment: ..and some overloads for logging other stuff.

Comment: It worked perfectly the way I wanted for my requirement. Thanks everyone. Cheers :)